# Swift Adding HTML to UIWebView, expression was too complex

Tags: ios, swift

I'm adding some HTML content to an UIWebView.

This line:

```
generatedHtml += "<br><p style=\"font-family:'Chevin-Medium';font-size:12px;color:#505050;padding-top:0px;\">" + newsItem.entry.likes + " like this " + newsItem.entry.comments?.count + " comments</p>"
```

I get:

```
expressions was too complex to be solved in reasonable time
```

I'm just doing a count on an array, i don't know how to make that less complex?

The object looks like this:

```
public class NewsItem: NSObject {
    var entry: EntryObject = EntryObject()

}

public class EntryObject: NSObject {
    var comments: [Comment]? = []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newsItem.entry.comments?.count` is an integer, and you can't add an integer to a string using `+`, you should use string interpolation with `\()`:

```
" like this \(newsItem.entry.comments?.count) comments</p>"
```

Or use the `String` initializer if you need to keep using `+`:

```
" like this " + String(newsItem.entry.comments?.count) + " comments</p>"
```

If the error "too complex" persists, you'll have to break down the statements and use variables instead of inserting the expressions directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do by this way

```
var countComments : Int = 0

//Validate comment counting
if let cComments = newsItem.entry.comments?.count
{
    countComments = cComments
}

//... Some code here ...

//Devide to Conquest.
//If is easy to find... Is not hard to fix
generatedHtml += "<br>"
generatedHtml += "<p style=\"font-family:'Chevin-Medium';font-size:12px;color:#505050;padding-top:0px;\">" 
generatedHtml += "\(newsItem.entry.likes) "  
generatedHtml += "like this \(countComments) comments"    //Here you have a valid value
genetatedHtml += "</p>"
```

But, why?

Maybe you have a problem with the optional value **newsItem.entry.comments?.count** that can gets you a nil value. Then, first of all, validate the value and be sure about what was returned. Better **"0"**, a valid value than **nil**

When you split the string creation, the debug working will be more easy to execute. You will can have a better idea where is happening an error.

Maybe it´s not a definitive solution to your problem, but a good way to help you fix it.